# Export in an if statement using meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, commonjs

it is fairly easy to *import* a file within an if statement like so:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  const thing = require('./blah').default;
}
```

However, what I am wondering is if you can export a default member of a module within an if statement without binding it to the global scope or window

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  export serverOnlyFunction = require('./blah').default;
}
```

How would this be accomplished in meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as you've written it, since exports must be defined at the top level (from [§A.5 of the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-scripts-and-modules)). This is related to how modules are handled when lazy-loading or circular dependencies occur and the code can't be executed during or before loading.

You can avoid this mess entirely by exporting the branch, rather than exporting from within a branch:

```
export function getTheFunction() {
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    return serverOnlyFunction;
  } else {
    return functionForEverybody;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, a wrapper function will work just as well:

```
export function wrapTheFunction(...args) {
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    return serverOnlyFunction.apply(this, args);
  } else {
    return functionForEverybody.apply(this, args);
  }
}
```

If you're using `exports` directly without the ES6 keyword, you could assign from within the branch:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  module.exports = serverOnlyFunction;
} else {
  module.exports = functionForEverybody;
}
```

But, unless you're stuck on ES5, this is poor practice. Exporting a function able to decide is a far more robust solution.

Secondly:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'; // <- is an import

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  const thing = require('./blah').default; // <- is *not* an import
}
```

`require` is not an import. They are two very different things with very different behavior. Furthermore, `require` is a runtime call made to an API provided by the runtime (node or requirejs) and return synchronously.

The correct ES6 equivalent would be:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  System.import('./blah').then((thing) => {
    // do something with thing
  });
}
```

Comment: Strangely, `System` exists in Meteor but does not have an `import` function

Comment: To my knowledge, no runtime provides a fully functional `System` object today. You need to use a library or bundler that implements it.